# Category theory and complexity classes

Tags: category-theory, computational-complexity

Is there any interesting way to make the set of computational complexity classes into a category? Almost every interesting mathematical class of objects forms a category after all.

Comment: Well, it's a poset, and posets are degenerate categories.

Comment: More or less a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178207/is-there-a-theory-that-combines-category-theory-abstract-algebra-and-computation

Comment: See also http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3074/a-category-of-np-complete-problems

Comment: @ZhenLin I was looking for something with maybe a bit more substance, maybe somehow encoding the idea of polynomial time reduction into the category in some meaningful way?

Comment: @RespawnedFluff Thanks, the cstheory link seems to be exactly what I am after.

Comment: You'll probably want some sort of enriched category.

Comment: At time of this comment, it appears there is a negative answer to this question on the cstheory stackexchange: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12207/is-there-a-theory-that-combines-category-theory-abstract-algebra-and-computation

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.07737